# Unable to read a line of text that is broken, from a text file- C#

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, sms, multiline

I add received messages to a **text file** that is read from a GSM Modem through a serial port. Later I parse these messages using **regular expressions** and display them in a list view. Receiving a message that is of a **single line** and displaying them is all fine but when I receive a message that has **multiple lines**, I am unable to read them. I guess I should change my regular expression that I use to parse. Suggestions please..

```
    public ShortMessageCollection ParseMessages(string input)
    {
        ShortMessageCollection messages = new ShortMessageCollection();
        Regex r = new Regex(@"\+CMGL: (\d+),""(.+)"",""(.+)"",(.*),""(.+)""\r\n(.+)\r\n");
        Match m = r.Match(input);
        while (m.Success)
            {
                ShortMessage msg = new ShortMessage();
                msg.Index = m.Groups[1].Value;
                msg.Status = m.Groups[2].Value;
                msg.Sender = m.Groups[3].Value;
                msg.Alphabet = m.Groups[4].Value;
                msg.Sent = m.Groups[5].Value;
                msg.Message = m.Groups[6].Value;
                messages.Add(msg);
                m = m.NextMatch();
            }

        return messages;
     }
```

`input` is a string variable which contains the data read from a file. 
A single line message in `input` is like this:

```
+CMGL: 1,\"REC UNREAD\",\"IA-612345\",\"\",\"2012/08/14 12:56:46+22\"\r\nRecharge with RC45 & get 100 local minutes valid for 15days.For details call 53640 (Toll Free)\r\n\r\n
```

A multiline message is like this:

```
+CMGL: 1,\"REC READ\",\"+919909965834\",\"\",\"2012/08/17 09:55:29+22\"\r\nHai helo\nthis is a\ntest mesg\r\n\r\nOK\r\n
```

How do I read the message part in the multiline message correctly and completely?

Comment: Will the message always start with `\r\n`?

Comment: Yes. It starts in a new line always

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a .Net `Regex` against text with multiple lines, you need to supply `RegexOptions.Multiline` as a constructor parameter:

```
public ShortMessageCollection ParseMessages(string input)
{
    ShortMessageCollection messages = new ShortMessageCollection();
    Regex r = new Regex(
        @"\+CMGL: (\d+),""(.+)"",""(.+)"",(.*),""(.+)""\r\n(.+)\r\n",
        RegexOptions.Multiline);
    Match m = r.Match(input);
    while (m.Success)
    {
        ShortMessage msg = new ShortMessage();
        msg.Index = m.Groups[1].Value;
        msg.Status = m.Groups[2].Value;
        msg.Sender = m.Groups[3].Value;
        msg.Alphabet = m.Groups[4].Value;
        msg.Sent = m.Groups[5].Value;
        msg.Message = m.Groups[6].Value;
        messages.Add(msg);
        m = m.NextMatch();
    }

    return messages;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but that dint make any difference. Multiline message does not match with the regular expression

Comment: If you post a sample of the target string containing the matches, I'll try and see what I can do about tweaking your `Regex` so it matches.

Comment: The single line message that I mentioned in the question matches the pattern that I wrote. You can refer that

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex.  It includes \r and \n as matchable characters in the last group.  One problem with this is that it filters out the \n and \r characters.  If you want to capture those also, you can remove the `?:` from the expression to make that capture work as well.

```
"\+CMGL: (\d+),""(.+)"",""(.+)"",(.*),""(.+)""\r\n([^\r]+)\r\n"
```

Comment: Dint work. That matched the whole data in my text file and it displayed all the content in the string as a single message :(

Comment: I did it allowing `?:` and without `?:` but both gave the same result

Comment: If all of these messages are stacked together with no other delimiter then it will be impossible to distinguish between the end of the last capture `(.|\r|\n)+` and the beginning of the first capture.  You're going to need some other kind of delimiter between the messages.

Comment: This is the message part in the multiline message `Hai helo\nthis is a \ntest mesg` . So now is it not possible in the last group that I can read these words along with `\n`? If this is possible, then rest is easy.

Comment: so please just let me know how do I read both `words` and `\n` in the last group

Comment: I see.  Then make the capture look like this: `(?:.|\n)+`  That should work.

Comment: Sorry still the same result, reads the whole string. I have used break points and observed that `msg.Message = m.Groups[6].Value;` in the code is reading the whole text file. So I think the problem is at this point. Anything to change here?

Comment: Are you still using the multiline option?  If so, try the expression `(?:.|\n)+` without it.

Comment: Im not using multiline option. This is what I am using:`Regex r = new Regex(@"\+CMGL: (\d+),""(.+)"",""(.+)"",(.*),""(.+)""\r\n((?:.|\n)+)\r\n");`

Comment: OK.  One more thought.  Change the end to say: `\r\n([^\r]+)\r\n`

Comment: I dint get it. Where do I add it? After the 6th group? It would be better if you could include it in my previous comment

Comment: On second thought, that won't work because there are extra \r\n's before the end of the full expression.  I go back to my original comment that you're going to need some other delimiter between messages.

Answer (score 0):

You might considering not trying to solve the entire problem using regex.  It looks like at least *part* of your data is structured, so you can use a regex for that.  For the actual body of the message, you can just read lines until there are no more, of you match a header again.

Try something like:

```
var r = new Regex(@"\+CMGL: (\d+),""(.+)"",""(.+)"",(.*),""(.+)""",
                  RegexOptions.Compiled);
var messages = new ShortMessageCollection();
using (var sw = new StringReader(input))
{
    string currentLine = sw.ReadLine();
    while (currentLine != null)
    {
        var m = r.Match(currentLine);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            // read the first line of the message
            string message = string.Empty;
            currentLine = sw.ReadLine();

            // Append any extra lines to our message, unless it's a new record
            while (currentLine != null && !r.IsMatch(currentLine))
            {
                message += Environment.NewLine;
                message += currentLine;

                currentLine = sw.ReadLine();
            }

            messages.Add(new ShortMessage
                             {
                                 Index = m.Groups[1].Value,
                                 Status = m.Groups[2].Value,
                                 Sender = m.Groups[3].Value,
                                 Alphabet = m.Groups[4].Value,
                                 Sent = m.Groups[5].Value,
                                 Message = message,
                             });
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: Log that a line didn't match
            // it could be empty or otherwise invalid
            currentLine = sw.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a rough outline of what you could do.  I would strongly suggest using an approach like this (not necessarily this code) over a single regex if you want to deal with very large bits of data.  This uses a TextReader, so it would immediately work if you were reading line by line from a file that was several GB large.